# Terraform Calling a Module from a module in another directory

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create a app configuration in azure. I am pretty sure this might be the wrong way to do this. So my folder structure for the app configuration and role assignment is something like this:

```
resources
|
|___
    main.tf
    variables.tf
    |
    └───appConfig
    │   │   appconfig.tf
    │   │   variables.tf
    │   
    └───roleAssignment
    |    │   roleAssignment.tf
    |    │   variables.tf
    |───functionApp
        │   functionApp.tf
        │   variables.tf
```

Now I am trying to create a role inside the appConfig.tf by consuming the roleAssignment.tf as a module/resource:

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appConfiguration" {
  name                       = var.name
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  location                   = var.location
  soft_delete_retention_days = var.soft_delete_retention_days
  sku                        = var.sku
  local_auth_enabled = var.local_auth_enabled
  tags = {
    env       = var.env
    owner     = var.owner
    CreatedBy = var.CreatedBy
  }
}

    ############################ App Config Data Owner Role ############################
    
    locals {
      roleAssignment = fileexists("${var.filepath}/roleAssignment/roleAssignment.json") ? jsondecode(file("${var.filepath}/roleAssignment/roleAssignment.json")) : null
    }
    module "roleAssignment" {
      source      = "../appRoleAssignment"
      for_each     = { for idx, element in coalesce(local.roleAssignment,[]) : idx => element }
      scope                = each.value.scope
      role_definition_name = each.value.role_definition_name
      principal_id         = each.value.principal_id
      description          = each.value.description
    }
```

The roleAssignment.tf looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "roleAssignment" {
  //name  = var.name
  scope = var.scope
  role_definition_name = var.role_definition_name
  principal_id         = var.principal_id
  description = var.description
}
```

I get the error here:

```
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on appConfig\appConfig.tf line 43, in module "appConfig":
│   43:     azurerm_role_assignment.roleAssignment
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "roleAssignment" has not been declared in module.appConfig.
```

I want the roleAssignment.tf to be reusable for other folders as well after the resources one like functionApp, keyVault etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error derives from config not present in the question, and so this answer must be somewhat speculative. You first need to declare an output in the `roleAssignment` module:

```
output "role_assignment" {
  value = azurerm_role_assignment.roleAssignment
}
```

and then you can access the module outputs from the config declaring the module. Since the attempt at accessing the exported attributes is not present in the question, an example is given:

```
resource "resource_type" "resource_name" {
  parameter = module.roleAssignment[idx].roleAssignment
}
```

where individual outputs must be accessed by the same index used in the module declaration (named as `idx` above to correlate to the config in the question), or else it can iterated upon as expected:

```
resource "resource_type" "resource_name" {
  for_each = module.roleAssignment
}
```

where each key correlates to `idx` and each value to an individual `roleAssignment` object as the type for `module.roleAssignment` is a `map`.

The structure and value of each `roleAssignment` output will correspond to each `azurerm_role_assignment.roleAssignment`. If you only need a single attribute, then you would probably want to refine the output value into something more granular.

More information about outputs can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs).